# Atualizar uma página com base nas informações de um chat

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho 2 sites, o primeiro eh o [www.chat.com.br](http://www.chat.com.br) e o segundo é [www.view.com.br](http://www.view.com.br).

> **Meu objetivo é:**
>    1 - Coletar os alertas do chat
>    2 - Atualizar o site view constantememte com os alertas coletados do chat.

O que pensei em fazer foi pegar os dados via javascript, fazer o chrome abrir em nova aba o [www.view.com.br](http://www.view.com.br) jogando a janela em uma variável e por último atualizando o html da view.

Porém me deparei com o `cross-origin`, e não consigo fazer com que a informação do chat chegue ao view.

> **Minha dúvida é :**
>    1 - Como fazer com que o site view receba as informações do site chat.
>    2 - Como fazer com que o view seja atualizando constantemente, sem que aja refresh.

Atualmente estou rodando o javascript por uma extensão que criei do chrome.

No site chat eles disponibilizam um campo para rodar js no backend.
Eu consigo usar isso para enviar dados para outro site?

Comment: Uma opção seria fazer requisições ajax a cada x tempo

Comment: Dá uma olhada em webSocket e vê se a sua necessidade se enquadra e se é possível utilizar com os seus recursos.